# SVG image badly scaled in IE11

Tags: javascript, css, svg, internet-explorer-11

I have an external SVG image that won't keep it aspect-ratio in IE11.

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
img {
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.wikipathways.org/wpi/wpi.php?action=downloadFile&type=svg&pwTitle=Pathway:WP3155_r80720" />
</div>
```

(https://jsfiddle.net/9q3cL4cs/7/)

The problem is that in IE11 the width is not scaled to match the max-height. The reason this doesn't work in IE11 is because the SVG image doesn't have a viewbox defined.

Any solutions are appreciated!

Comment: "The reason this doesn't work in IE11 is because the SVG image doesn't have a viewbox defined." Solution: add a `viewBox`?

Comment: The SVG image is from an external website, so I cannot change it. I have tried to load it with JS and then add a viewbox, but my attempts failed.

Comment: The image is scaled right in IE 11.187.14393.0

Comment: When will IE disappear?

Comment: You should not be responsible to fix another service's bug. If the service returns a broken SVG, they must fix it. You can still do a proxy inbetween otherwise (server-side in PHP or client-side in JS maybe using BlobUri).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the url of the image and download it.

Open the image in GIMP or Illustrator somewhere you can get the SVG code.

Get that code and paste it to your html.

Then play with the view box attribute until you get the right scaling.

Also now you can change anything in your SVG.

If you use SVG inside a container div it is useful to use

```
svg{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

in the CSS.

Because with this rule SVG sizes connects with their container divs.

In my experience it is **always** better to use plain SVG XML code for any operation about SVG.

Comment: Not possible because it has to work with thousand of different images, all coming from different sources, with all different aspect ratios. Also the `max-height` in the CSS is the most important property here.

Comment: Ok then challenge starts again :) Let me think more.

Comment: First idea : Well why not make AJAX requests to that urls, get the content, write to DOM modify their viewBox's or any attributes? Would it be slow for you?

Comment: Indeed one solution I have thought of is to get the image with js, use a MIME-checker plugin to see if it's an SVG image (unfortunately not all files have proper extensions), if it is a SVG file, parse it and check if the viewbox is defined, if not so, add a viewbox attribute based on the hopefuly defined width and height. But this looks a bit cumbersome for something that work out of the box on all the other browsers ;).

Comment: Well the same line of thought and better. I can't think of any other solution because of the dynamic content. I will write if something comes up.